# Moving images in Java

Tags: java, image, swing, jframe

I want to make an image that I drew in the paint class move left across my `JFrame` as a timer ticks. But  I don't know how to do that. Also, I am trying to get my program to make the image disappear when the image is clicked upon.

#### movingball class

```
import java.awt.Graphics2D;    
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.awt.geom.Ellipse2D;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.Timer;

public class movingball extends JPanel{

    private int move=50;
    private Timer timer = new Timer(move, new TimerListener());
    private int radius = 10;
    private int x = 300;    
    private int y = 0;

    public  movingball() {
          timer.start();
    }

    private class TimerListener implements ActionListener{
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e){
        x=x-20;
        repaint();  }//trying to get the oval to move left 20 
    }

    protected void paintComponent(Graphics2D g){
    super.paintComponent(g);
    g.fillOval(x, 100 , radius * 2, radius * 2);    }
    }
```

#### movingControl class

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.event.InputEvent;
import java.awt.event.ItemEvent;
import java.awt.event.MouseAdapter;
import java.awt.event.MouseEvent;    
import javax.swing.JPanel;

public class movingControl extends JPanel {

private movingball ball= new movingball();

public movingControl(){
    JPanel panel = new JPanel();
    ball.setBorder(new javax.swing.border.LineBorder(Color.red));
    panel.addMouseListener(new movingballListener());
    setLayout(new BorderLayout());
    add(ball, BorderLayout.CENTER);
    add(panel, BorderLayout.SOUTH);
}
}
```

#### SnniperGameApp class

I know I spelled sniper wrong

```
import javax.swing.JApplet;

public class SnniperGameApp extends JApplet {

static final long serialVersionUID = 2777718668465204446L;
//i dont know what this serial thing is. But my program wont start without it

public SnniperGameApp(){
    add(new movingControl());
}
}
```

#### ClickingEvent class

```
import java.awt.event.InputEvent;
import java.awt.event.ItemEvent;
import java.awt.event.MouseAdapter;
import java.awt.event.MouseEvent;

class movingballListener extends MouseAdapter{

    public void mouseReleased(MouseEvent e) {
        if ((e.getModifiers() & InputEvent.BUTTON1_DOWN_MASK) != 0) {
          System.out.println(  (e.getPoint()));}}
    }
```

Comment: For better help sooner, post an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/).

Comment: On cursory glance, it looks like the ball should move. What happens instead?

Comment: Please learn common [Java nomenclature](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/jls/second_edition/html/names.doc.html) (specifically the case used for the names) for class, method & attribute names & use it consistently.

Comment: @AndrewThompson Sorry, I'm new at java and trying to learn. I will work on that.

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels The ball just sits there on the Jframe.

Comment: The MovingBall class works fine for me when I fix the paintComponent method and stick it in a plain JFrame.

Comment: @DNA: indeed it does! 1+

Comment: Thanks for all the input. The ball moves now. Is there an easier way to code a click event?

Answer (score 3):

You haven't over-ridden `paintComponent()` properly.

From [the javadoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/swing/JComponent.html#paintComponent%28java.awt.Graphics%29), the signature of `paintComponent()` is:

```
protected void paintComponent(Graphics g)
```

but you have:

```
protected void paintComponent(Graphics2D g)
```

The method signatures must match - you can safely cast the `Graphics` to a `Graphics2D` inside the method if needed.

Adding the `@Override` annotation to a method is a good way to get the compiler to check that you *really are* over-riding a method, not just writing a method that looks the same!

---

Here's a working SSCCE (I have inlined some of the constants to save space, don't take that as good practice for real code!):

```
public class MovingBall extends JPanel
{
    private Timer timer = new Timer(50, new TimerListener());
    private int x = 300;

    public MovingBall()
    {
        timer.start();
    }

    private class TimerListener implements ActionListener
    {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
        {
            x -= 20;
            repaint();
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void paintComponent(Graphics g)
    {
        super.paintComponent(g);
        g.fillOval(x, 100, 20, 20);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        JFrame frame = new JFrame();
        frame.add(new MovingBall());
        frame.setSize(500, 500);
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }
}
```